# How to Replace text inside tag in Notepad ++ from 2 file Xml?

Tags: notepad++, xml

Example:

File 1:

```
<CannonExp.xml>
<String>
    <ID>    1   </ID>
    <ASCII> Memiliki beberapa Giant crossbow yang dapat menyerang jarak jauh. Kelemahan fortress ini adalah defensenya yang masih lemah.    </ASCII>
    <Unicode>   TQBlAG0AaQBsAGkAawBpACAAYgBlAGIAZQByAGEAcABhACAARwBpAGEAbgB0ACAAYwByAG8AcwBzAGIAbwB3ACAAeQBhAG4AZwAgAGQAYQBwAGEAdAAgAG0AZQBuAHkAZQByAGEAbgBnACAAagBhAHIAYQBrACAAagBhAHUAaAAuACAASwBlAGwAZQBtAGEAaABhAG4AIABmAG8AcgB0AHIAZQBzAHMAIABpAG4AaQAgAGEAZABhAGwAYQBoACAAZABlAGYAZQBuAHMAZQBuAHkAYQAgAHkAYQBuAGcAIABtAGEAcwBpAGgAIABsAGUAbQBhAGgALgA=    </Unicode>
</String>
<String>
    <ID>    2   </ID>
    <ASCII> Dapat melemparkan batu besar yang menyebabkan serangan area. Kelemahan fortress ini adalah jarak serangannya yang terlalu pendek.   </ASCII>
    <Unicode>   RABhAHAAYQB0ACAAbQBlAGwAZQBtAHAAYQByAGsAYQBuACAAYgBhAHQAdQAgAGIAZQBzAGEAcgAgAHkAYQBuAGcAIABtAGUAbgB5AGUAYgBhAGIAawBhAG4AIABzAGUAcgBhAG4AZwBhAG4AIABhAHIAZQBhAC4AIABLAGUAbABlAG0AYQBoAGEAbgAgAGYAbwByAHQAcgBlAHMAcwAgAGkAbgBpACAAYQBkAGEAbABhAGgAIABqAGEAcgBhAGsAIABzAGUAcgBhAG4AZwBhAG4AbgB5AGEAIAB5AGEAbgBnACAAdABlAHIAbABhAGwAdQAgAHAAZQBuAGQAZQBrAC4A    </Unicode>
</String>
<String>
    <ID>    3   </ID>
    <ASCII> Dapat menembakkan banyak misil pada saat yang bersamaan. Kekuatan serangan besar dan kecepatan serangan yang tinggi. Memiliki kemampuan rata-rata.  </ASCII>
    <Unicode>   RABhAHAAYQB0ACAAbQBlAG4AZQBtAGIAYQBrAGsAYQBuACAAYgBhAG4AeQBhAGsAIABtAGkAcwBpAGwAIABwAGEAZABhACAAcwBhAGEAdAAgAHkAYQBuAGcAIABiAGUAcgBzAGEAbQBhAGEAbgAuACAASwBlAGsAdQBhAHQAYQBuACAAcwBlAHIAYQBuAGcAYQBuACAAYgBlAHMAYQByACAAZABhAG4AIABrAGUAYwBlAHAAYQB0AGEAbgAgAHMAZQByAGEAbgBnAGEAbgAgAHkAYQBuAGcAIAB0AGkAbgBnAGcAaQAuACAATQBlAG0AaQBsAGkAawBpACAAawBlAG0AYQBtAHAAdQBhAG4AIAByAGEAdABhAC0AcgBhAHQAYQAuAA==    </Unicode>
</String>
```

File 2:

```
<CannonExp.xml>
<String>
    <ID>    1   </ID>
    <ASCII> Phao ?ai phong th? dung c? n? b?n ten nhi?u l?n t?n cong c? ly xa, s?c phong ng? h?i y?u la khuy?t ?i?m c?a no  </ASCII>
    <Unicode>   UABoAOEAbwAgABEB4ABpACAAcABoAPIAbgBnACAAdABoAOceIABkAPkAbgBnACAAYwDxHiAAbgDPHiAAYgCvHm4AIAB0AOoAbgAgAG4AaABpAMEedQAgAGwApx5uACAAdAClHm4AIABjAPQAbgBnACAAYwDxHiAAbAB5ACAAeABhACwAIABzAOkeYwAgAHAAaADyAG4AZwAgAG4AZwDxHiAAaAChAWkAIAB5AL8edQAgAGwA4AAgAGsAaAB1AHkAvx50ACAAEQFpAMMebQAgAGMA5x5hACAAbgDzAA==    </Unicode>
</String>
<String>
    <ID>    2   </ID>
    <ASCII> Phao ?ai phong th? kien c? va co kh? n?ng nem nh?ng t?ng ?a l?n t?o sat th??ng ph?m vi, t?m b?n h?i ng?n la nh??c ?i?m c?a no   </ASCII>
    <Unicode>   UABoAOEAbwAgABEB4ABpACAAcABoAPIAbgBnACAAdABoAOceIABrAGkA6gBuACAAYwDRHiAAdgDgACAAYwDzACAAawBoAKMeIABuAAMBbgBnACAAbgDpAG0AIABuAGgA7x5uAGcAIAB0AKMebgBnACAAEQHhACAAbADbHm4AIAB0AKEebwAgAHMA4QB0ACAAdABoALABoQFuAGcAIABwAGgAoR5tACAAdgBpACwAIAB0AKcebQAgAGIArx5uACAAaAChAWkAIABuAGcArx5uACAAbADgACAAbgBoALAB4x5jACAAEQFpAMMebQAgAGMA5x5hACAAbgDzAA==    </Unicode>
</String>
```

File after Replace:

```
<CannonExp.xml>
<String>
    <ID>    1   </ID>
    <ASCII> Phao ?ai phong th? dung c? n? b?n ten nhi?u l?n t?n cong c? ly xa, s?c phong ng? h?i y?u la khuy?t ?i?m c?a no  </ASCII>
    <Unicode>   UABoAOEAbwAgABEB4ABpACAAcABoAPIAbgBnACAAdABoAOceIABkAPkAbgBnACAAYwDxHiAAbgDPHiAAYgCvHm4AIAB0AOoAbgAgAG4AaABpAMEedQAgAGwApx5uACAAdAClHm4AIABjAPQAbgBnACAAYwDxHiAAbAB5ACAAeABhACwAIABzAOkeYwAgAHAAaADyAG4AZwAgAG4AZwDxHiAAaAChAWkAIAB5AL8edQAgAGwA4AAgAGsAaAB1AHkAvx50ACAAEQFpAMMebQAgAGMA5x5hACAAbgDzAA==    </Unicode>
</String>
<String>
    <ID>    2   </ID>
    <ASCII> Phao ?ai phong th? kien c? va co kh? n?ng nem nh?ng t?ng ?a l?n t?o sat th??ng ph?m vi, t?m b?n h?i ng?n la nh??c ?i?m c?a no   </ASCII>
    <Unicode>   UABoAOEAbwAgABEB4ABpACAAcABoAPIAbgBnACAAdABoAOceIABrAGkA6gBuACAAYwDRHiAAdgDgACAAYwDzACAAawBoAKMeIABuAAMBbgBnACAAbgDpAG0AIABuAGgA7x5uAGcAIAB0AKMebgBnACAAEQHhACAAbADbHm4AIAB0AKEebwAgAHMA4QB0ACAAdABoALABoQFuAGcAIABwAGgAoR5tACAAdgBpACwAIAB0AKcebQAgAGIArx5uACAAaAChAWkAIABuAGcArx5uACAAbADgACAAbgBoALAB4x5jACAAEQFpAMMebQAgAGMA5x5hACAAbgDzAA==    </Unicode>
</String>
<String>
    <ID>    3   </ID>
    <ASCII> Dapat menembakkan banyak misil pada saat yang bersamaan. Kekuatan serangan besar dan kecepatan serangan yang tinggi. Memiliki kemampuan rata-rata.  </ASCII>
    <Unicode>   RABhAHAAYQB0ACAAbQBlAG4AZQBtAGIAYQBrAGsAYQBuACAAYgBhAG4AeQBhAGsAIABtAGkAcwBpAGwAIABwAGEAZABhACAAcwBhAGEAdAAgAHkAYQBuAGcAIABiAGUAcgBzAGEAbQBhAGEAbgAuACAASwBlAGsAdQBhAHQAYQBuACAAcwBlAHIAYQBuAGcAYQBuACAAYgBlAHMAYQByACAAZABhAG4AIABrAGUAYwBlAHAAYQB0AGEAbgAgAHMAZQByAGEAbgBnAGEAbgAgAHkAYQBuAGcAIAB0AGkAbgBnAGcAaQAuACAATQBlAG0AaQBsAGkAawBpACAAawBlAG0AYQBtAHAAdQBhAG4AIAByAGEAdABhAC0AcgBhAHQAYQAuAA==    </Unicode>
</String>
```

Let me know Plsss..

Comment: For such a simple change why don't you use cut and paste?

Comment: i have 100 file xml with >50.000line per one.

Comment: Then you need to explain more clearly what are the rules for the replacement. Your examples don't show this.

Comment: Please explain the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rather off-the-wall approach that I have sometimes used.  Say you want to get text from File A into File B, sandwiched by certain other text in File B.

Step 1: For each file, copy the entire contents into Word.  Do some careful text replacement to prepare for a Convert text to table.  Copy this table over to Excel.  Reformat as needed, remove columns, rows or cells as needed.

Step 2: Set up a Mail Merge (catalog type) in Word, drawing data from both files, with the needed XML code as window dressing.

Step 3: Copy the output and paste into a new Notepad++ file.